# Changing privacy of old Facebook posts using the Graph API

Tags: php, python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

So I was flicking through my Facebook Timeline, and started to look at some old posts I made in 2009~2010. And they're a bit stupid and I'd like to remove them or change the privacy settings on them.

There are too many to do it individually, so I've been looking at the Graph API. However, I have been unable to find anything about changing the privacy settings of posts, or even searching for posts made in a specific date range.

So here is the information that I want:

**Is it possible to change privacy settings for OLD posts via the Graph API?**

**Is it possible to search the Graph API for posts in a particular date range?** Preferably before 31st December 2010.

If it is possible, how do you do it!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Nope.
2) Yes, you can use the Graph API and HTTP Get `me/feed?until={date}`